# EmberJS - How to call `parent` component method from `child component`

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

From my `rootcomponent` i am passing data to `child component`. I can able to pass the data by assigning the `model` to attribute. same say, my `root component` having `on change` method function, how to call it from `child component`.

Meaning, I don't want to keep another `js` file for my `child component`. let me keep all my `actions` with `root component` and with multiple `hbs` files.

here is my root component code : ( sending data to child component )

```
<div class="balanceEmi rdc-scroll-content has-subheader rdc-view">
    {{cs2i-select-tenure selectedCreditCard=model}}
</div>
```

here is child component hbs file:

```
    <div class="rdc-panel-content">
            <h6 >
                {{selectedCreditCard.attributes.cardName}}
                {{rdc-label text=(card-no-display selectedCreditCard.attributes.cardNo)}}
            </h6>
            <div class="rdc-form-content">
                {{#rdc-form-select label="Pay To" 
                    labelPosition="top" tabindex="0"
                    options=selectedCreditCard.relationships.balances.data
                    selected="Please select a Balance"
                    searchEnabled=false
//how to call onchange to parent component?
                    onchange=(action this.attrs["selectedBalaceType"] ) as |type|
                }}
                {{type}}
                {{/rdc-form-select}}
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: There may be some problem if you are having `type` property in `card-list` model.

Comment: @kumkanillam - can you please help here to communicate from child component to parent component?

Comment: Usually we need to pass action too like this `{{cs2i-select-tenure onChangeBalance=(action 'onChangeBalance')}}`. so you need to define `onChangeBalance` this in the context where you are calling the `cs2i-select-tenure`.  and in `cs2i-select-tenure` you can use it directly like `<button {{action onChangeBalance}}> OnChange </button>`..

Comment: I will encourage you to write and share https://ember-twiddle.com with minimal code, that will help us to give concrete answer easily

Comment: yes, you are correct, But I am using no.of internal component which I can't able to reproduce there

Comment: Put your assumption into twiddle and ask why this is not working , it will be easy for us to identify the issue.

Comment: yes, I have intergrated your suggesion getting error as `Assertion Failed: An action named 'selectedBalaceType' was not` - but it is declared in parent component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151244/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-3gwebtrain).